# Classification of negative customer feedback into categories on the basis of text analysis in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to categorize negative customer feedback after customer care calls into 5 categories that I came up with after wordcount and manual work.I am new to NLP. I am using R.
The customer feedback is in a CSV.I wish to add another column in the CSV as 'Category'. The feedback looks like this:

**General Feedback**

None

I don't think he could understand English very well.  I had trouble understanding what he was saying because of his thick accent. 
PLEASE HAVE ENGILISH SPEAKING REPRESENRATIVES!!!

?

I needed help with my bill. I guess I'll just let it cancel.  I have a different card. I'm not being petty. I had information that would help you with other customers. Your rep was very rude.

?

?

?

She is an idiot. She tried very hard to blame anyone other than the company for the problem. Her diagnosis defied any logic. She put me on hold and never came back. Ultimately, she did (I assume) get the service to work again, and she claims to have given me 6 months free for the inconvenience, but, overall, your customer service has been consistently terrible.

?

?

?

?

I am really thinking of cancelling.  Pay for what has been currently used.
Someday I hope to find out about my service, the dates, and the bill.
When a customer says NO, no means no and STOP talking over the customer in an attempt to get them to extend their contract... All this does is aggravate the customer and for me makes my decision to terminate the contract that much more

?

Reading my e-mail this a.m. I have signed up for 1 month and another for 6 mos. How?? This is not what I want
Why should I continually have to call customer care?  I have asked your representatives to put a note in the comments that when they see my phone number to automatically refresh the signal.  They on the other hand have to ask me again over and over for my phone number, address, email account and id.  I  absolutely hate, the customer service of your company.

?

Totally discussed with company rep right now.

?

you need to hire representatives who speak english*

The categories are based on wordcountso all I have done so far is some textual analysis.I don't understand how to go ahead with this?
I have thought of using probabilistic models like naive bayes classifier but i don't know how to apply it on my case? Any suggestions/help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please read up basics of NLP and sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of bad phrases and good phrases then simply count the occurrences of the phrases in the text. A high count of bad phrases will determine the score and thus the category. Greater than 10 would be Worst and so on.

Bad:

terrible
horrible
thick accent
idiot
rude
mean
never again
never came back
left on hold
bad
not helpful
cancel
aggravate
terminate